# Read CSS selector in excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, css-selectors

I have inspected elements on a page and I am trying to got the css selector for specific row in a table. I right-click the element and Copy CSS for that row and I got

```
#content > table.stripe.asking-price-table.property-table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)
```

How can I refer to such selector in VBA?
here's the HTML part

```html
<tr>
    <td><a class="nolink" href="/for-sale/houses/al1/">Houses</a></td>
    <td>
        <strong class="price">£245,891</strong><br>
        (<a href="/for-sale/houses/1-bedroom/al1/">11</a>)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong class="price">£464,431</strong><br>
        (<a href="/for-sale/houses/2-bedrooms/al1/">16</a>)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong class="price">£729,583</strong><br>
        (<a href="/for-sale/houses/3-bedrooms/al1/">12</a>)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong class="price">£1,086,174</strong><br>
        (<a href="/for-sale/houses/4-bedrooms/al1/">17</a>)
    </td>
    <td>
        <strong class="price">£1,331,667</strong><br>
        (<a href="/for-sale/houses/5-bedrooms/al1/">3</a>)
    </td>
</tr>
```

I tried such a line but got an error

```
Set tbl = html.querySelectorAll("table.stripe.asking-price-table.property-table tbody tr:nth-child(1)")
```

Comment: Please include more of your code (is this via xhr for example?) and the actual error message. The url would also be most useful (the html supplied is not sufficient to run the css selector) and the expected output.

Comment: Thanks a lot my tutor. It seems the problem was not with the CSS selector. It was in assigning the variable html. I have tried till it is fixed. Thank you very much.

Comment: It's unclear what the issue you are facing with your current attempt @YasserKhalil. If you are using IE then `:nth-child(1)` will work when you defined the same within `.querySelector()` but fail miserably if you use the same when you go for `XMLHTTP60` because the latter doesn't support pseudo selector. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes you are right. I was using `XMLHTTP60 ` so this throws error.